# SQL Server service stopped unexpectedly event ID 17310 and 17311

Tags: c#, sql-server

SQL Server 2014 SP3 CU4 service terminates suddenly with the errors id 17310 and 17311.
The dump errors file show following stack:

```
Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0067.txt
SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process 57 generated fatal exception c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. SQL Server is terminating this process.



BEGIN STACK DUMP:
   01/25/21 19:09:36 spid 57


   Exception Address = 00000000D4AF1840 Module(UNKNOWN+0000000000000000)
   Exception Code    = c0000005 EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
   Access Violation occurred writing address 00000000D4AF1840
 Input Buffer 510 bytes -
             INSERT INTO IntestazioneDoc (Id,TipoDoc,NumDoc,Agente,CodCli,
  DataDoc,DataEvasione,Acconto,Note,Sc1,Sc2,Sc3,DocAgg,Stato,DetailsCount,
  Anagrafe_Id,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,Deleted) SELECT Id,TipoDoc,NumDoc,Agente
  ,CodCli,DataDoc,DataEvasione,Acconto,Note,Sc1,Sc2,Sc3,DocAgg,Stato,Detai
  lsCount,Anagrafe_Id,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,Deleted FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQL
  NCLI', 'Server=***').myDb.dbo.IntestazioneDoc WHERE CreatedAt > '25/01/2021 11:39:37 +00:00'
```

Also, here there is another error:

```
2021-02-28 22:50:26.86 spid58      Errore: 17311, gravità: 16, stato: 1.
2021-02-28 22:50:26.86 spid58      SQL Server is terminating because of fatal exception 80000003. This error may be caused by an unhandled Win32 or C++ exception, or by an access violation encountered during exception handling. Check the SQL error log for any related stack dumps or messages. This exception forces SQL Server to shutdown. To recover from this error, restart the server (unless SQLAgent is configured to auto restart).
2021-02-28 22:50:26.89 spid58      **Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x0000000038AD0D90
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      ***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0094.txt
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      * *******************************************************************************
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *   02/28/21 22:50:26 spid 58
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      * ex_handle_except encountered exception 80000003 - Server terminating
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      * Input Buffer 510 bytes -
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *             INSERT INTO Anagrafe (Id,CodCli,Descrizione,PartitaIva,Indiri
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *  zzo,CAP,Localita,Prov,CodAli,Listino,Sconti,Note,Fido,FidoMax,Esposizion
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *  eMax,Esposizione,MaxOrdinabile,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,Deleted,Aliquote_Id,B
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *  loccato,Nuovo,Soggetto,Nome,Cognome,Sesso,Telefono,Cellulare,CodiceFisca
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *  le,CodiceDestinatario,Privacy,CondizioniVendita) SELECT Id,CodCli,Descri
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *  zione,PartitaIva,Indirizzo,CAP,Localita,Prov,CodAli,Listino,Sconti,Note,
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *  Fido,FidoMax,EsposizioneMax,Esposizione,MaxOrdinabile,CreatedAt,UpdatedA
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *  t,Deleted,Aliquote_Id,Bloccato,Nuovo,Soggetto,Nome,Cognome,Sesso,Telefon
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *  o,Cellulare,CodiceFiscale,CodiceDestinatario,Privacy,CondizioniVendita F
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *  ROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI', 'Server=***').myDb.dbo.An
2021-02-28 22:50:26.91 spid58      *  agrafe WHERE CreatedAt > '25/02/2021 15:18:33 +00:00'
```

Is there something that I should do in my program to fix this issues?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using an out-of -support version?

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server log files?

Comment: @jdweng: yes, I got the errors reported from the log files

Comment: I would run task manager on SQL Server machine while running and check memory usage.  See :https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-17066-or-17310-during-sql-server-startup-4f0919a9-3a7a-fa04-ace5-0cbcb539f0f2 and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/63e1d6a8-12f9-4b98-a39d-339ea11765ad/issue-in-sql-server-2016?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: The server uses about 30% of total memory, so I think isn't a memory issue. But maybe the issue is caused by linked servers (the query links to Azure using OpenDataSource statement). But I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research and testing, I found that the problem was caused by 2 asynchronous processes running the above query at the same time.
Since there was a trigger in the tables on which the query was executed, its execution raised the exception which then stopped the SQLServer service. I solved it by serializing the query execution.